# Magento replace add to cart button with image

Tags: image, magento, button, replace

Is it possbible to replace the magento "add to cart" button with a custom image?

I think I have to change something in template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml but don't know how to replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on template hints.

By default catalog pricing uses this template in product listing. You need to hunt it down for product view as well.

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml

Find the button html:

Line 61:

```
<p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
```

Replace html with something like...

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>">
<input type="image" src="source/to/my/image.jpg" />
</a>
```

Unfortunately Magento uses prototype to update quantities for the button so you may need to muddle with adjusting the javascript when you click the new image.

Comment: When I look at the button with template hints it showes the following phtml files: addto.phtml (for wishlist), addtocart.phtml and priceclone.phtml. Any changes made to list.phtml show no change. So I think I have to replace some code in addtocart.phtml.

Comment: Dear Vladimir, after playing around with your information I could get it to work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use css to replace the button with the image.

Below is the simple example to do so

```
.button-cart{
background-image url(http://i47.tinypic.com/2ni0ahd.png) 3px 5px no-repeat;
}
```

Here, **button-cart** is the class that you can use to select the button and provide the background image as you wish.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I can only find .add-to-cart button.button { and when I add background-image there nothing happens. I think the problem is that the regular "button" is no image as it contains text which is also translated and can be changed. Sorry but didn't help me